# How to check for concurrent requests on an Apache/PHP based server?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, database-performance

I was wondering if there is a way to catch concurrent requests on an Apache/PHP server. By doing so we could potentially increase our application's performance. To illustrate my point, here is an example:

Consider an endpoint: `/add_post`. It simply adds a post to the database. Imagine that our server receives 10 concurrent requests. That'll be 10 different MySQL queries. But if we could catch these incoming (concurrent) requests we could, in principle, complete the job using a single MySQL query. And that would, of course, increase performance. Or would it?

Comment: Are you looking at "throughput" (web pages per second)?  Or "latency" (how fast does this page load)?

Answer (score 0):

It would not make a noticeable difference if the MySQL-Server runs on the same machine or at least on a machine in the same data center so that the latency doesn't matter. MySQL is very fast and therefore it is no problem to execute many queries.

You should instead try to speed up the bootstrapping and algorithms of your PHP application. They have a much greater impact on the performance of your server.

Answer (score 0):

In order to combine Apache/PHP requests, you would have to stand on your head.  This would take far more effort and time than the savings you might get.

Phrased differently, HTTP request are independent of each other.  Combining them is messy, complex, and slow.

Your other question...  "Are batched `INSERTs` faster than individual inserts?"  The answer is yes.  A single `INSERT` with 100 rows runs 10 times as fast as 100 one-row `INSERTs`.  But, I repeat, it is not worth doing in the scenario you describe.

Apache+PHP can easily handle deliver dozens, perhaps hundreds, of web pages *per second*.  If your implementation cannot, then the solution is *not* by trying to combine pages.